# Change catalog taxonomy URLs

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8, ubercart

How do I change the Ubercart catalog taxonomy URLs in Drupal 8? When I view my catalog, I have URLs like catalog/1 and catalog/2. How do I change them into catalog/taxonomy-term-name?

(I can't find in view settings something like *Convert term name to ID*.)

Answer (score 0):

The source for the header of (Catalog views)  is from a second view 
(catalog terms view)      you can make changes there

make term id hidden and term name visible

Comment: thanks. But if I look in the setup from the Ubercart view `Taxonomy term: Term-ID` is already hidden. If I click there on the field `Taxonomy term: Name` in rewrite result I tried for path (of the link) `catalog/{{ name }}`. But thats not working? What do I have to do?